# How to enable conversion of Spark UDT to another type with the same representation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-types, internals

I'm using Spark 2.4.3 and I have defined a custom type `FastString` which helps me to avoid conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16 (`UTF8String` to `java.lang.String`) and back.

Unfortunately Spark cannot convert `String` to my type `FastString`. This

```scala
Seq("foo").toDF.as[FastString]
```

fails with exception:

```
cannot resolve 'CAST(`value` AS STRING)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to string;
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(`value` AS STRING)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to string;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$3.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:278)
```

The culprit is `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.canCast` function. Unfortunately I don't see any way how to extend the `canCast` function to support my type `FastString` (note reimplementing `acceptsType` in my `FastStringUDT` doesn't help).

So my question is how to implement `FastString` to be comptabile with Spark's `StringType` the same way as `java.lang.String` but without too much code (eg. without reimplementing whole `ExpressionEncoder` and `ScalaReflection`)?

Here is definition of `FastString` and `FastStringUDT`:

```scala
package org.apache.spark.sql.radekm

import java.io.{Externalizable, ObjectInput, ObjectOutput}

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.{Input, Output}
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.{Kryo, KryoSerializable}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, SQLUserDefinedType, StringType, UserDefinedType}
import org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String

@SQLUserDefinedType(udt = classOf[FastStringUDT])
case class FastString(s: UTF8String) extends Comparable[FastString] with Externalizable with KryoSerializable {
  override def compareTo(o: FastString): Int = s.compareTo(o.s)

  override def writeExternal(out: ObjectOutput): Unit = s.writeExternal(out)
  override def readExternal(in: ObjectInput): Unit = s.readExternal(in)

  override def write(kryo: Kryo, output: Output): Unit = s.write(kryo, output)
  override def read(kryo: Kryo, input: Input): Unit = s.read(kryo, input)
}

private[spark] class FastStringUDT extends UserDefinedType[FastString] {

  override def sqlType: DataType = StringType

  override def pyUDT: String = "pyspark.sql.radekm.FastStringUDT"

  override def serialize(p: FastString) = p.s
  override def deserialize(datum: Any): FastString = {
    datum match {
      case value: UTF8String => FastString(value.clone())
    }
  }

  override def userClass: Class[FastString] = classOf[FastString]
  private[spark] override def asNullable: FastStringUDT = this
}
```

Comment: For reference, it seems it's currently blocked by UDT not being a part of the public API: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28889